# script for starting multiple and the same programs in Win10 AND positioning them over 3 monitors

Tags: powershell

i start with apologize for having hardly any coding experience, but i thought this is the right place for my question.

Using WIN10 and have 3 monitor setup.
Q:for some tasks i need to open 4 times explorer.exe each with a different folders, start internet_explorer and on other software program and that the different windows are in a specific place over the 3 monitors.
The 4 explorer windows on left monitor (one in upper left corner, one in upper right etc. software program (max window) on center monitor and internet explorer on right monitor; left side.

My search on internet give me answers to open different software programs with batch ore powershell but i can't find how to set up opening 4 times the same program and positioning over 3 monitors.
I don't know if the positioning of the different windows is even possible.

I hope someone can help me or point me in the right direction. Is there a softwareprogram that will do as ask.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the easiest way to do this is to use [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com).

It has methods like [WinMove](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMove.htm) to move windows around the screen however you want. The [WinMove](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMove.htm) documentation includes an easy example of how to launch a program and move it to a desired location.

Comment: tnx for the reply. i'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

start "iexplore" "Website"

start "explorer" "path"